# AngularJS $http.get() not working

Tags: php, angularjs, zend-framework2

I am using ZF2 and AngularJS to create a Quiz Application. When I am running the code, No error occurs, and no result.

```
(function(angular) {
function MainController($scope,$http) {
    $scope.question = function(id)
    {
        var site = "http://localhost/zf/public/interviewer";
        var page = "/jsonquestion/"+id;
        alert(site + page);
        var reqQuestion = $http.get(site + page);
        reqQuestion.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {$scope.question.questions = data;});
        reqQuestion.error(function(data, status, headers, config){alert("AJAX failed!");});
        alert(data);
    }
};
angular.module("app", []).controller("MainController", ["$scope", MainController]);
```

})(angular);

My zend part is

```
public function jsonquestionAction()
 {
   $id = (int) $this->params()->fromRoute('id', 0);
   $questions = $this->getQuestionsTable()->getQuestions($id);
   $result = json_encode($questions);

   $myfile = fopen("newfile.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
   fwrite($myfile, $result);
   fclose($myfile);

   echo $result;
   return $result;
 }
```

When I m calling  `http://localhost/zf/public/interviewer/jsonquestion/1` from browser its working and returning Json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't injecting $http to your controller
Try changing to this.

```
angular.module("app", []).controller("MainController", ["$scope", "$http", MainController]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Shot in the dark.  Your zend function is called jsonquestionAction, but your page call is made to jsonquestion.

Maybe changing this:

```
 var page = "/jsonquestion/"+id;
```

To this:

```
var page = "/jsonquestionAction/"+id;
```

Will help.

Comment: Thank you.I tried it. But not working. The code is working up to alert(site + page);